# What is wrong with my message passing example?

Tags: recursion, erlang, message-passing, erlang-shell, hotswap

I am attempting to send a message from one process that I spawned to another for an assignment, I feel like I am very close here, but I think my syntax is just a bit off:

```
-module(assignment6).
-export([start/1, process1/2, process2/0, send_message/2]).

process1(N, Pid) ->

    Message = "This is the original Message",

    if 
        N == 1 ->
            timer:sleep(3000),
            send_message(Pid, Message);

        N > 1 ->
            timer:sleep(3000),
            send_message(Pid, Message),
            process1(N-1, Pid);

        true ->
            io:fwrite("Negative/0, Int/Floating-Point Numbers not allowed")
    end.

process2() ->
    recieve
        Message ->
            io:fwrite(Message),
            io:fwrite("~n");
    end.

send_message(Pid, Message) ->
    Pid ! {Message}.

start(N) ->
    Pid = spawn(assignment6, process2, []),
    spawn(assignment6, process1, [N, Pid]).
```

The goal of this program is that the Message, will be printed out N times when the function is started, but be delayed enough so that I can hot-swap the wording of the message mid-run. I just can't quite get the Message to `process2` for printout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Four small things:

- It's spelled `receive`, not `recieve`
- Remove the semicolon in `process2`.  The last clause in a `receive` expression does not have a terminating semicolon.  You can see this in the `if` expression in `process1`: the first two clauses end with a semicolon, but the third one does not.
- In `process2`, print the message like this:

  ```
  io:fwrite("~p~n", [Message])
  ```

  Since `Message` is a tuple, not a string, passing it as the first argument to `io:fwrite` causes a `badarg` error.  Let's ask `io:fwrite` to format it for us instead.
- `process2` should probably call itself after printing the message.  Otherwise, it will receive one message and then exit.

---

So now you can run the code, and while it's running you can load a new version of the module with a different message (so called "hot code swapping").  Will that change the message being printed?  Why / why not?

> It won't.  `process1` does a *local* call to itself, which means that it stays in the old version of the module.  Do an external call instead (explicitly specifying the module: `assignment6:process1(N-1, Pid)`), and it will switch to the new version.

Comment: Thank You! These suggestions worked immensely, also, I can't spell :/. Hot Swapping should work now i believe? All i have to do is recompile it while it is running right? I just have to switch what the message actually says.

Comment: Fantastic! You are a life saver. Erlang has been an exceptionally interesting language to get my feet wet with. Thank You for the help again.

Comment: Glad to hear! I added the note about hot code swapping into the answer itself, properly hidden as a spoiler.